# IDL - Cropping GeoTiff with IDL (no Envi)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, clip, pixel, idl

How can I crop a GeoTiff (EPSG:4326) in IDL by using pixel coordinates, and then saving the cropped files with the correct georeferencing?

I assume I have to re-set the information in the MODELTIEPOINTTAG in the GEOTIFF-Structure? 
If I understand that tag correctly, it contains (in my case) the coordinates of the Upper-Left corner in Degrees positive in East and North direction:

```
MODELTIEPOINTTAG={0, 0, 0, 90.08, 23.63, 0}
```

So basically I can just crop the image by pixel coordinates, and then convert the pixel-coordinates of the upper-left crop-point into Lat-Lon coordinates (in the original image frame) and write them into the MODELTIEPOINTTAG, but leave every other tag the same, correct?

Do I take the corner of the for that, or the center (i.e. add 0.5 to the pixel coordinates)?

How can I accomplish this in IDL? Are there already methods available for that?

Comment: An alternative approach could be to just create a `gdal_translate` or `gdal_warp` command string and then launch it using `spawn`°

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I used gdal_translate and the -srcwin switch, works perfectly!